# Android worker with foreground service does not show notifications

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-workmanager

I'm following [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/long-running#long-running) to create a long-time worker running a foreground service, but no notification is shown.

The worker run, i see the logs.

The code:

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    Log.d(TAG, "Worker start")
    setForeground(createForegroundInfo("Hello from my notification"))
    Log.d(TAG, "Worker end")
    return Result.success()
}

private fun createForegroundInfo(progress: String): ForegroundInfo {
    val channelId = applicationContext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id)
    val title = applicationContext.getString(R.string.notification_title)
    // This PendingIntent can be used to cancel the worker
    val intent = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
        .createCancelPendingIntent(getId())

    // Create a Notification channel if necessary
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createChannel()
    }

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, channelId)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setTicker(title)
        .setContentText(progress)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp)
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build()

    return ForegroundInfo(1, notification)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun createChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    val name = applicationContext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_name)
    val descriptionText = applicationContext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_description)
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    val channelId = applicationContext.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id)
    val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance).apply {
        description = descriptionText
    }
    // Register the channel with the system
    val notificationManager: NotificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}
```

Comment: To make the notification appear, call NotificationManagerCompat.notify()-> https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#notify

Comment: In the Worker documentation it is not mentioned to use the manager to show the notification, I expect the function `setForeground` to show it.
I quote the documentation: `Calls setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo(myProgress)) periodically when it needs to update the ongoing Notification`.

Comment: In debug mode, setForeground shows the notification but however I remove the debug mode it dismisses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `doWork` function lasted too short, not long enough to see the notification.

Answer (score 0):

when you create your notification for **getForegroundInfo()** add
.setForegroundServiceBehavior(FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE) for NotificationCompat.Builder and your notification will be shown immediately